# Auto Capitalise Words

Tags: jquery, capitalize

How would I go about getting this script to capitalise letter if its next to numbers or symbols. This is my code at the moment. So if its next to "1" or "-" it would come up as "1A" "-A" instead of "1a" "-a"

```
$.fn.capitalise = function() {
  $.each(this, function() {
    var split = this.value.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
      split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    this.value = split.join(' ');
  });
  return this;
};

$('#id1').on('input', function() {
  $(this).capitalise();
}).capitalise();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match a non-alpha character followed by an alpha character, and then convert it to uppercase on all matches. The below snippet will capitalize after a number/symbol or whitespace as you type.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.capitalise = function() {
    //get existing value from input
    let currentValue = $(this).val();
    //apply regex replace to uppercase characters after number/symbol/whitespace
    let newValue = currentValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])/g,  function(match) {
      return match.toUpperCase();
    });
    //set new value to input
    $(this).val(newValue);
  };

  $('#id1').on('input', function() {
    $(this).capitalise();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="id1">Type here to auto-capitalize after number/symbol/whitespace:</label>
<br/>
<input id="id1"/>
```

If capitalizing after whitespace is not desired, just add `\s` to the first part of the regex:

```
/[^a-zA-Z\s]([a-zA-Z])/g
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Andrew. Theres a little problem, it doesn't capitalise the first letter on the input, it only capitalises after the first word or space.

Comment: Also, it shouldn't allow whole words in all caps, only the first letter.